# How can I turn on Unity again

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

I'm just a newbie switching to ubuntu for a few day.
I accidentally turn off the unity interface in the ccsm (compiz something I don't know)
Now, my desktop don't have anything except my computer, home folder, and trash.
Many (or all) shortcut keys are disable.
I can only access the internet by going through folders in my computer. 
And this place is my only last hope before I decide to reinstall it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logout or reboot your system. When you select your username on the login screen [change the session to "Ubuntu Classic"](http://ihaveapc.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Ubuntu-11.04-Classic-Gnome-Session-001.png). When you are on the Desktop go to ["Applications menu -> Accessories -> Terminal"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#In%20Gnome) then type "unity --reset" in the terminal and hit Enter.

Reboot your system again. In the same location you switched to Classic, you have to choose Unity again.

In Unity you can access your terminal or any other application [with the dash.](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try running `unity --reset` to reset the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast reply :)
But could you give me more specific instructions to do it. I just switch to ubuntu for just few days.

Comment: @Pipat Here's the detailed version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you so much. 
I use ctrl+alt+f1 to switch to full screen terminal
and use your "unity --reset"
then type "sudo reboot"
everything is back normal again like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop has an icon that says 'My Computer', you must be running Windows. If you have Ubuntu installed, reboot, and select it from the boot menu.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but that is not a case.
I select to jump into ubuntu as default setting. 
Luckily, the problem was solved.